# How to publish new version of app for specific devices on Google Play

Tags: android, google-play

Soon I'm going to release new version of my app. It is a huge change and I'd prefer to release if for a narrow list of devices. Google Play offers an option to manage excluded devices, but as far as I understand it will affect all versions of this app, and I'd like to avoid that. Is there a way to manage excluded devices only for one version?

Example:
Current production version is 1.0 and it supports 8000, now I want to release 2.0 only for 100, but I want the 1.0 be still available for those 7900 devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you're looking for is called staged roll-outs. [Google support has more information about it here](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213?hl=en), I think what you want is "set up a staged rollout on production".

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Staged roll-out is even better that the thing I asked in my question. Thanks!